# Select only distinct columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2005, distinct

i have table T and want select only distinct columns (without correlation between fields)

```
F1  F2  F3
 1   A   AA
 1   B   BB
 2   B   CC
 2   C   DD
 2   C   EE
 3   C   EE
```

desired output

```
 F1   F2   F3
 1    A    AA
 2    B    BB
 3    C    CC
 null null DD
 null null EE
```

i try

```
select T.F1, T1.F2 from
(select distinct F1, row_num() rn from T) T
left join (select distinct F2, row_num() rn from T) T1 on T.rn=T1.rn1
left join etc...
```

can it be simpler?

Comment: Your desired output doesn't make sense with distinct, as the only non distinct row is `2   C`

Comment: @Maxrem i cant see any pattern in your example, it doesn't make sense, the two column example before you edit might be relevant and can be  achieve by using `row_number`

Comment: i dont need pattern or correlation between fields

Comment: @Maxrem doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**Example for two columns.** 
SELECT t1.f1, t2.f2
    FROM
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY f1) AS num, f1 FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT f1 FROM T
    ) AS t1
    ) AS t1
    FULL JOIN 
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY f2) AS num, f2 FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT f2 FROM T
    ) AS t2
    ) AS t2 ON t2.num = t1.num
```

Comment: Thank you, i use this approach

Answer (score 1):

> Input:
>
> ```
> F1  F2
> 1   A
> 1   B
> 2   B
> 2   C
> 2   C
> 3   C
> ```
>
> Desired output:
>
> ```
> F1  F2
> 1   A
> 2   B
> 3   C
> ```

Based on the input provided, this produces the desired output too:

```
SELECT F1, MIN(F2) AS F2
FROM T
GROUP BY F1;
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter what you mean?

Comment: @Maxrem it really doesn't make sense that way.

Comment: i dont need pattern or correlation between fields